# calling a function

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Hi i have a function on a class which is like this :

```
- (Float32)averagePower {   
    if (![self isListening])
        return 0.0;
    float tmp = [self levels][0].mAveragePower;
    tmp = tmp * 100;
    NSLog(@"%f",  tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

i am calling it from viewdidload of another class like this:

```
SoundSensor *theInstance = [[SoundSensor alloc] init];
    [theInstance listen];
    Float32 tmp;
    [theInstance averagePower:tmp];
```

now i can call to listen but when calling to averagepower i got warning that it may not respond and the function is crashing in simulation.
what i do wrong ?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a variable to a function that accepts no parameters.

What I expect you meant to do is this:

```
Float32 tmp = [theInstance averagePower];
```

Comment: Thanks but when i do that he say: unused variable 'tmp' . so how should i call it  ?

Comment: ok when i do this :  Float32 tmp ; and then make the the assignment in another line , its working. strange,i dont get that, but thanks a lot

Comment: You get "unused variable" warnings because you are assigning the variable but not using it yet.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the method with a parameter:

```
 [theInstance averagePower:tmp];
```

but it does not have any parameters in its definition:

```
- (Float32)averagePower {
// ...
}
```

This is causing the crash. If you are trying to assign the return value of the method to the `tmp` variable, you should do this:

```
Float32 tmp = [theInstance averagePower];
```

To get rid of the warning make sure you declare this method in the interface block of the corresponding class (the h file).